# What supplemental resource do you recommend in order to fully comprehend The Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, statistical-learning

I am learning the book "Elements of Statistical Learning," but it is very hard because it requires very heavy knowledge about statistics, which I have some, but apparently not enough to understand the derivations in the book. For example, 
[image]

this is the derivation for the expected prediction error for the linear model Y=beta*X + epsilon. I don't understand it at all! This is very frustrating, and I would really loved to be able to understand this book. Can you tell me some resources using which I can beef up my foundations (whatever it may be) necessary in order to fully comprehend ESL?

Comment: I would recommend several MOOCs on edx, Coursera, or similar websites.

Comment: Study probability (theory) and linear (matrix) algebra.

Answer (score 2):

The same authors have a more introductory book called Introduction to Statistical Learning. There is a free PDF version online http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/